# Python3: unable to install evdev on Stratodesk/Notouch OS --> unable to execute 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, python-3.x, gcc, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install evdev package on Raspberry Pi with an operating system "Stratodesk" or "NotouchOS". However, when executing the following command:

```
pip3 install evdev
```

I used pip3

```
pip3 --version
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

I get this error:

```
Collecting evdev
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/6e/3fa84a43571dec4d00dc26befccc9867b6b3263651531cbc1345f718860f/evdev-1.2.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: evdev
  Building wheel for evdev (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/run/tmp/pip-install-a7k9k2x3/evdev/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /run/tmp/pip-wheel-q8aze50n --python-tag cp35:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/util.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/uinput.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/genecodes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/ff.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/evtest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/events.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/eventio_async.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/eventio.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/ecodes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/device.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  copying evdev/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  running build_ext
  running build_ecodes
  writing ecodes.c (using /usr/include/linux/input.h /usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h /usr/include/linux/uinput.h)
  building 'evdev._input' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c evdev/input.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/evdev/input.o -std=c99
-Wno-error=declaration-after-statement
      unable to execute 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for evdev
```

if someone has come cross this before with a solution

FYI:

```
uname -a
```

> Linux Raspi4 4.14.78-v7+ #1156 SMP Tue Oct 23 14:34:39 BST 2018
>   armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

**UPDATE**
using python 2.7, the package was installed successfully!

```
pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

However, I would still prefer to use python 3.5.2 (the installed version) as the software was developed on Python 3.5

Comment: When working on a RaspberryPi, you use the `gcc` native compiler; not the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` cross-compiler. File a bug report against the folks providing the package (`evdev`?). In the old days, you simply `CC=gcc` and them `make`. But folks reinvented the build system, and figured out ways to make it fancier that did not work. *q.v.*

Comment: thank you. I am using the same package on Raspian OS with no problem. But this is `stratodesk` or `notouch` os https://www.stratodesk.com/kb/Main_Page . btw, I also tried to execute `gcc` on its own `bash: gcc: command not found`

Comment: Install your build tools. [how do I install build tools on RaspberryPi](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+do+I+install+build+tools+on+RaspberryPi).

Comment: Thanks. using pip of Python 2.7 didn't show any problem. That's weird. on other OS, pip3 is working just find. the only difference I can recall is that on the other devices the version of python3 is `3.5.3` while on this device `3.5.2` Plus to different OS 'raspian' vs 'notouch'